# android push notification using gcm

Tags: c#, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing wcf push notification service using google's GCM API. i created a service which sends to all the device which use my application but, i wanted to be specific to some device. i am thinking i have to use the token i get when i register for the GCM service. but i dont know where and how to implment it. most of the online posts are in PHP and i am kind of confused when i see the codes. Any one with C# implmentation advice or in general may be?
here is my code for all the devices:

```
 public bool notify(string sender, string message)
    {
        var jGcmData = new JObject();
        var jData = new JObject();
        bool Value;

        jData.Add("message", message);
        jData.Add("name", sender);
        jGcmData.Add("to", "/topics/global");
        jGcmData.Add("data", jData);

        var url = new Uri("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                    "Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);

                Task.WaitAll(client.PostAsync(url,
                    new StringContent(jGcmData.ToString(), Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
                .ContinueWith(response =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                    Console.WriteLine("Message sent: check the client device notification tray.");
                }));
            }
            Value = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to send GCM message:");
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            Value = false;
        }
        return Value;
    }
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1st of all I think you should not reinvent the wheel and include a Push messaging library to do all the redundant work.

[I use PushSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushSharp/)

Then everything is cake.

Declare the following handler class
Using the SendGCMNotification method just throw an object to serialize and a specific user's push messaging id .

```
    public class PushNotificationHandler : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly string googleApiKey;
    private static PushBroker pushBrokerInstance;
    static PushNotificationHandler()
    {
        googleApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAPIKey"].ToString();
        pushBrokerInstance = new PushBroker();
        pushBrokerInstance.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings(googleApiKey));

    }
    public static void SendGCMNotification(Notification messageObj, String CloudMessagingId)
    {
        String Content = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObj);
        pushBrokerInstance.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(CloudMessagingId).WithJson(Content));
    }
}
```

Comment: i saw lot of posts using pushSharp, i will take a look at it. Thanks!